# Angular Widget using jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, popup, angularjs-controller

I am trying to write a widget which will show up on button click. 
This is a jQuery representation of what I want to achieve. 
[jQuery (This is not my code. Found this one on net)](http://jsfiddle.net/rjGeS/83/) 
I am not sure how to go on with the development. Should the directive needs to an element or an attribute or something else. 
I have not tested this as I am not sure about going on about this. This is how I planned to do.

```
angular.module('common').directive('shareModal',function (){

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    show: '=',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        $(elem).click (function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $("#background").css({
                 "opacity": "0.3"
            }).fadeIn("slow");

            $("#large").html(function() {
                $('.ttip').css({
                                   left: $this.position() + '20px',
                                   top: $this.position() + '50px'
                               }).show(500)

            }).fadeIn("slow");

            $('.note').on('click', function() {
                $('.ttip').hide(500);
                $("#background").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#large").fadeOut("slow");

            });
            $("#large").click(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut();
            })
        })
    }
}});
```

Thanks in advance.

Update:
The Custom Popover is what I am trying to achieve. [Custom Popover](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##popovers)

Comment: Also, getting a
Unknown provider: $popoverProvider <- $popover <- shareModalDirective error.
The error I believe is due to no [Controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=scopeProvider%20%3C-%20scope%20%3C-%20shareModalDirective)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by injecting the module 'mgcrea.ngStrap'